# Why Backbone collection loads all the models after I .fetch() if `model` property is specified?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

When I `.fetch()` on `Collection` it loads all the items from REST API:

`GET /api/model/post`

But if I specifying `model` property in `Collection` - it also tries to load all the models one by one

```
GET /api/model/post
GET /api/model/post/565a5d78769a92f34b2cfc05
GET /api/model/post/565a5da32f303b3e4cb5fd79
GET /api/model/post/565a5dcea1faba894cf33ba7
...
```

Should it do that? All the data supposed to be provided when collection is loaded...

**UPD:** Problem solved, see comment below.

Comment: I don't think it does that... Can you share the code..?

Comment: I just started to compose example for you and figured it out, I think. In my model I added `.fetch` inside `initialize` which triggers if an `id` is passed to the model, and now I understand that that was a bad idea. Thank you anyway for triggering it! ;) There is an example how was that done http://pastebin.com/a4Ev6atX